# Regarding Fingerprint reader

Tags: fingerprint-reader

I have ASUS Vivobook which has fingerprint sensor. So my question is does anyone knows how to make it work in Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS?

Comment: And what methods did you try to make it work?

Comment: I tried all the methods already mentioned on this website. But none of them works.

Comment: Just mentioning I have done everything won't work. Mention what you tried and what output you got. The less information you give out lesser the chances of getting help. Try to install the drive for fingerprint sensor. Look for the driver's name and after you're installing check it out and explain the whole process in here